# What is the correct statement of this "theorem" about 2-factorability of graphs?

Tags: graph-theory

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_factorization#2-factorization):

> If a graph is $2$-factorable, then it has to be $2k$-regular for some
>   integer $k$.

This can't be right:

[image: graph with 2-factor]

> **Question.** What's the correct statement of this "theorem" about $2$-factorization
>   of graphs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the graph $G$ is 2-factorable, it means that $G$ can be decomposed into 2-factors so that the 2-factors, taken together, cover every edge of the $G$.

The example you gave does not have such a decomposition because the grey subgraph is not a 2-factor.

Comment: I think your first sentence is incorrect. A factor of $G$ is simply a subgraph that has the same vertex set as $G$. A $k$-factor is a factor that happens to be $k$-regular.

Comment: I'm not trying to define a 2-factor. I'm trying to define what it means for a graph to be 2-factorABLE.

Comment: Oh, I see. What do we call the weaker condition that there exists a $k$-factor?

Comment: I don't think such a term exists...